# Excel #SPILL! error when there is nothing else in the spill range

Tags: excel-formula, spill-range

In cell A1 i have the following:
`=TOCOL(E1:G6,3)`
In Cell B1 i have the following
`=UNIQUE(VSTACK(E1:E6,F1:F6,G1:G6))`
In cells E1 to G6 I have this formula
`=LET(RandNum,RANDBETWEEN(1,100),IF(RandNum>90,NA(),RandNum))`
There is nothing else on this worksheet.
I press F9 to recalculate and every now and again (with no apparent pattern) Cells A1 and B1 show #SPILL! errors.
Is there a valid reason for these #SPILL! errors or is this a bug in excel?

It appears to be as a result of the varying result range rather than anything being present in the spill range. If you copy and paste the range as values and re-calculate then A1 and B1 calculate just fine. It appears to be some sort of issue with the varying result range and the way spill formulas are calculated behind the scenes. It can sometimes take a while for this error to come up. It may come up more frequently if I change >90 to >50 so the variation in the size of the spill range is greater.

Comment: My understanding is that the #SPILL! error should only occur when something is in the spill range. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-spill-error-spill-range-isn-t-blank-182c7141-7ff5-4dc2-ba38-7a81b7bf51c7

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023  see the part of indeterminate size.

Comment: Thanks, it still seems odd that it functions correctly most of the time but errors intermittently.

Comment: It is a known issue, not sure if Microsoft has plans to fix or not.

Comment: Curious now as to how to resolve this question? Should i remove the question or would you or I answer it with reference to the MS explanation - that spill ranges cannot reliably cope with volatilty?

Comment: I believe there is duplicate out there, I just do not have time to hunt for it.

Comment: Feel free to self answer, just in case no one can find the dup.

Answer (score 1):

According to this support article...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023

"Dynamic array resizes may trigger additional calculation passes to ensure the spreadsheet is fully calculated. If the size of the array continues to change during these additional passes and does not stabilize, Excel will resolve the dynamic array as #SPILL!."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023

Thanks to Scott Craner for the useful comments. Hope this helps someone else.